# Cant compile code when I use GradientFill() function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, compiler-errors

I get a compile error when I use the function GradientFill(); in my Native WinAPI C++ application

What am I doing wrong? How can I get my code to compile? I am using **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express**.

In my project I have linked the correct library msimg32.lib file. See below for all my linked files(Project Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies):

> comctl32.lib;kernel32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;msimg32.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Compile Error:

> 1>c:\users\app.cpp(129): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 6 arguments

The code that causes the compile error:

```
void TransparentCheckbox::verticalGradient(HDC hDC, const RECT& GradientFill, COLORREF rgbTop, COLORREF rgbBottom)
{
    GRADIENT_RECT gradientRect = { 0, 1 };
    TRIVERTEX triVertext[ 2 ] = {
        GradientFill.left - 1,
        GradientFill.top - 1,
        GetRValue(rgbTop) << 8,
        GetGValue(rgbTop) << 8,
        GetBValue(rgbTop) << 8,
        0x0000,                 
        GradientFill.right,
        GradientFill.bottom,
        GetRValue(rgbBottom) << 8,
        GetGValue(rgbBottom) << 8,
        GetBValue(rgbBottom) << 8,
        0x0000
    };

    // Below is line 129
    GradientFill(hDC, triVertext, 2, &gradientRect, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_V);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared a parameter; **GradientFill** as **const RECT&**, and then call the Windows GradientFill procedure - this is leading to a conflict.  I would change the the name of the parameter, or you could scope the procedure call as **::GradientFill**.

Comment: thanks. I feel like such an idiot lol, I thought it was some major linker error not just a clash of parameter/function names lol. MVC++ needs more informative compile error descriptions though

Comment: @JakeM, GCC's is informative enough for me. It's something like `GradientFill cannot be used as a function`. I suppose once you see it a couple times, you'll immediately recognize it later, regardless of how detailed the error message is.